# Simple, Cyclic and Projective Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

I have been taking a course in Homological Algebra and revisiting the lecture notes for some reason. There was a non-answered question about showing two non zero modules A,B over a non trivial unital ring(in fact upper triangular matrices) are projective modules. I won't explain what these modules are because it requires a lot of work.

I thought that if there is a relation between being cyclic and/or simple AND projective then I can use that. However, I couldn't find any such relation.

Is there any relation between cyclic and/or simple modules and projective modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All modules are nonzero in the following discussion.

- Simple modules are cyclic. In fact, every nonzero element of a simple module can act as a generator. Indeed, let $M$ be a simple module and $x \in M$ be a nonzero element of $M$. Let's consider the submodule $Rx$ generated by $x$ in $M$. Since $M$ is simple and $Rx \neq 0$, it has to be $M$, i.e. $M=Rx$. This shows that $M$ is cyclic.
- Every cyclic module can be written as a quotient of the *regular module* $R$ (i.e. $R$ is viewed as an $R$-module.) In fact, let $M=Rx$ for some $x \in M$, then consider the annilihaltor of $x$, i.e.
  $$
  \mathrm{ann}_{R}(x) = \{ r \in R : rx=0\}.
  $$
  Then it is the kernel of the left multiplication map
  $$
  \ell_{x}: R \rightarrow M=Rx;\quad r \mapsto rx.  
  $$
  This is clearly surjective. Hence by the isomorphim theorem, we have
  $$
  M \cong R/\mathrm{ann}_{R}(x).
  $$
  Hence if $x$ is a torsion free element (i.e. $\mathrm{ann}_{R}(x)=0$), then $M$ is a free $R$-module of rank 1.
- Free modules are projective. (This is shown in most of the homological algebra textbooks.)

This is what I can think of among simple modules, cyclic module and projective modules. Sorry for any possible mistakes and misleadings. :)

**EDIT**: Glad to see that this answer is helpful. As a reply to the comment, I shall add a few things.

*Item 1*: There are examples of cyclic modules that are not simple. Examples are rich when we go back to (finitely generated) $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, i.e. abelian groups. This case is much more clearer since we can apply both the group-theoretic facts and the structure theory of finitely generated modules over PID. For finite $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (i.e. finite abelian groups, or say finitely generated abelian groups with no free parts), it is inspiring to consider the following problems:

- Classify all cyclic finite $\mathbb{Z}$-modules and all its possible $\mathbb{Z}$-submodules;
- Classify all simple (or irreducible) finite $\mathbb{Z}$-modules;
- Classify all indecomposable finite $\mathbb{Z}$-modules;
- Classify all semisimple finite $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.

If one hopes to get more familiar to examples, one can substitude the $\mathbb{Z}$-modules in above questions to $F[X]$-modules to invoke linear algebra stuff. (Here $F$ is a field, maybe one can assume $F$ is algebraically closed of characteristic 0, or say $F =\mathbb{C}$. I haven't consider these questions over $F[X]$, but it seems quite illustrating.)

Still feel not quite enough after tried the above two cases? Then what about considering a family of linear operators acting on the vector spaces? Say we have two commuting linear operators on the vector space $V$, then we can shift to consider $F[X,Y]$-module. This is quite complicated (and I haven't tried by hand and I'm not suggesting you to do this and the follows in this paragraph). If we have a *group* of linear operators, say a finite group $G$ acting on $V$, then we are actually considering the $F[G]$-modules. With a little bit modification, we now step into the field of group representation theory. There, classifying irreducible $F[G]$-modules and see how a reducible one decomposes is the main topic in a first course on representation theory of finite groups. For infinite groups, things can even be much more complicated.

You mentioned modules over upper triangular matrices. Then it maybe relevant to the case that a family of upper-triangulariable operators acting on a vector space? (Actually in finite dim'l vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$, all linear operators are upper-triangulariable if I haven't got it wrong.)

> Sorry I have said so many irrelevant stuff to the question. Yet it excited me so much when I first realized such things before.

Or in general, one may prove that

- A projective module over a PID is precisely a free module;
- An injective module over a PID is precisely a divisible module (requires Baer's criterion);
- A flat module over a PID is precisely a torsion-free module.

*Item 2*: Actually there is a description of projective modules: An $R$-module $M$ is projective iff it is a direct summand of a free module $R^{\oplus I}$. This may help in some cases and might be usefull when describing the relation among simple/cyclic/projective modules.

Comment: I should be more clear. The module A can be a cyclic but not simple module. It is my mistake. But your answer is enough for me. Thank you so much for this detailed answer. 

I also edited the question a bit. 

What if we have a cyclic but not simple module?

Comment: I have add something and hope that these can help.

Comment: I think that "cyclic but not simple module" question is a littile bit too broad for me to give a rather concrete answer.

Comment: @nomadd If you are satisfied with this answer, you may click the green "√" button under the vote so that this can be cleared up from the unanswered list. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for an extra very detailed answer. I clicked on the green button. I thought about this yesterday and we couldn't find a relation between cyclic but not simple modules and projective modules. The things you wrote are so important. Also we know that free => projective => flat. What do we know about injective modules? Do we have such a chain? I guess not because free does not need to imply injective modules, right?

Comment: @nomadd There is a chain "cofree -> injective -> divisible (in a sense that is not too widely used.)"  But cofree and divisible modules are somehow less used/well-known than their counterparts.  Maybe somewhat interestingly to you, an injective submodule of $R_R$ is necessarily cyclic.  But in general simple modules bear no relation to injective modules.

Comment: I totally agree with what @rschwieb has added above and have no more to add. :)

Comment: @rschwieb I took a look at the definition of cofree modules. Why there is a special attention to Q/Z? What are reasons behind considering Hom(-,Q/Z)?

Comment: Actually I am trying to develop ideas in the following question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4266950/module-over-a-path-algebra

Comment: I was trying to show which S_0, S_1 and P_1 projective and injective. Apparently, S_0 and S_1 are projective. I don't know what is P_1. I guess it is injective but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: @nomadd I do not have an explanation for the motivation of the definition of coffee modules.  If I were better at category theory I could do it. Also, you do realize that projective and injective are not mutually exclusive, right?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes I know that in some cases projective modules can be injective and vice versa. In order to have that, I guess the ring should be field. In the case where the ring is a ring not a field, a projective cannot be injective and vice versa.

Comment: @nomadd no, that last sentence is what I was warning against.  Some modules are both projective and injective, even for rings other than fields

Comment: @rschwieb Oh really? But is the lemma in the answer of the question false? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513653/the-relationship-of-free-divisible-projective-injective-and-flat-modules?rq=1

Comment: @rschwieb Ok I got it. Over semisimple rings injective modules are projective and vice versa.

Comment: @nomadd Well yes... that is even true for quasi-Frobenius rings. But anyhow, I was not quantifying over all modules. I just meant that a projective can be injective and an injective can be projective. It just depends on the module.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought that if there is a relation between being cyclic and/or simple AND projective then I can use that.

1. A simple module is always cyclic ( every nonzero element generates it.)
2. A projective cyclic module need not be simple (for example $R_R$ for any ring that isn’t a division ring.)
3. A simple module need not be projective.  (For example, $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is not projective as a $\mathbb Z$ module.)

I think this takes care of all the possible mixtures of relationships that you could test.  There is very little to say positively.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have been reading your valuable answers in algebra while I was doing some research. Could you please give more details about your R_R example?

Comment: @nomadd $R_R$ is free, hence projective (or you could just prove it is projective directly.)  It's cyclic because it's generated by $1$.  If it's not a division ring, it isn't a simple module. What else is there to say?